# NURBS Weights De Boor's Algorithm

Tags: math, linear-algebra, computational-geometry, bezier, nurbs

I am having trouble implementing an algorithm for 3rd degree NURBS.
I have been able to program 2nd degree ones from the equations described [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/996281/NURBS-curve-made-easy) but I am not able to derive an equation for Rational B-Splines of degree 3. The author describes the Rational Knot Equation as [image: NURBS] that is a non-recursive form of the [De Boor's Algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Boor%27s_algorithm) from there I was able to program **Rational Internal Control Points: Bn** and **Cn** as:

```
/* Note that I had to modify the equations to work from the first point on the list as the ones described in the article only took into account points from the second index **Pn+1**. I though that could have been the problem and rewrote them as they where originally written but that did not solve the issue, so I am posting the ones that work from **Pn** */

// Point B. 
/* Iterate over the points(3d vector), knots(double) and weights(double) lists to get the Internal Control Points(3d vector) for the 3rd degree Bézier curves. */

 // Precompute:
double knotE = ( knots[i + 4] - knots[i + 2] ) / ( knots[i + 4] - knots[i + 1] );
double knotEO = ( knots[i + 2] - knots[i + 1] ) / ( knots[i + 4] - knots[i + 1] );

double rationalWeight = (  weights[i] * knotE ) + ( weights[i + 1] * knotEO );
double w1 = weights[i] / rationalWeight;
double w2 = weights[i + 1] / rationalWeight;

/* Our Point3d class lets us multiply a vector by a scalar. */
Point3d b = new Point3d( ( knotE * points[i] * w1 ) + ( knotEO * points[i + 1] * w2 ) );

// Point C. 
/* Iterate over the points, knots and weights lists to get the Internal Control Points for the 3rd degree Bézier curves. */

 // Precompute:
double knotE = ( knots[i + 4] - knots[i + 3] ) / ( knots[i + 4] - knots[i + 1] );
double knotEO = ( knots[i + 3] - knots[i + 1] ) / ( knots[i + 4] - knots[i + 1] );

double rationalWeight = (  weights[i] * knotE ) + ( weights[i + 1] * knotEO );
double w1 = weights[i] / rationalWeight;
double w2 = weights[i + 1] / rationalWeight;

/* Our Point3d class lets us multiply a vector by a scalar. */
Point3d c = new Point3d( ( knotE * points[i] * w1 ) + ( knotEO * points[i + 1] * w2 ) );
```

But when I apply the same process for point **Vn** I get results that are not the ones I am looking for:

```
// Point V. 
/* Iterate over the c, b, knots and weights lists to get the Internal Control Points for the 3rd degree Bézier curves. */

 // Precompute:
double knotE = ( knots[i + 4] - knots[i + 3] ) / ( knots[i + 4] - knots[i + 2] );
double knotEO = ( knots[i + 3] - knots[i + 2] ) / ( knots[i + 4] - knots[i + 2] );

double rationalWeight = (  weights[i] * knotE ) + ( weights[i + 1] * knotEO );
double w1 = weights[i] / rationalWeight;
double w2 = weights[i + 1] / rationalWeight;

/* Our Point3d class lets us multiply a vector by a scalar. */
Point3d v = new Point3d( ( knotE * c[i] * w1 ) + ( knotEO * b[i + 1] * w2 ) );
```

When all the weights are the same the points respond as expected, when the weights are not the same points **Bn** and **Cn** work as they should but **Vn** responds incorrectly. So my **Vn Equation** must be wrong. As the function inputs **Bn** and **Cn** lists of points my guess is that I am missing a relationship between those two equations with the one I am having trouble with.

As my problem is with the mathematical concept instead of an inplementation this is considered a language agnostic question.

Here's a picture of a 3d degree UniformBSpline [image: UBS] which I programmed succesfully already but that may help if the link to the resource goes down.

Comment: Did you have a lookt at https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#bsplines by any chance? (the main text is the "required base information", the very last section explains how to rational'ize it)

Comment: Thanks! The thing here is that this formula that I am using doesn't use the recursive De Boor's so I have to unroll the **x * w -> x / w** for a deeper recursion step.

Comment: rather than fully unroll, you can almost always rewrite "recursion" to "a normal for loop" (which as a general programming rule, you should wherever possible =D). In this case that means you use a single for loop but with intermediate caching, which speeds things up a bit, too.

Comment: Yes! Thats the point of using this algo, but what I mean is solving the formula by hand so I save more computations. Something like when we use the algebraic substitution of higher degrees of Bézier instead of doing lerp of lerp of lerp if that makes sense. I'll post the answer here when I get to it.